# Remove the 'All' DAT value rows which has multiple DAT values for 1 ID and one of them is 'All'

Tags: sql, hive

How to remove the 'All' DAT value rows which has multiple DAT values for 1 ID and one of them is 'All'. However if the val has only 'All' as the DAT value we should include those rows:

Sample input:
[image]

Sample output:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Van exact duplicates exist?  Could `1, a, All` exist twice, for example?

Comment: no, it can't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a `select` query, then window functions can be helpful:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum( case when data <> 'All' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id, val) as cnt_notall
      from t
     ) t
where not (data = 'All' and cnt_notall > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM
  your_table
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM your_table  lookup
     WHERE lookup.id   = your_table.id
       AND lookup.val  = your_table.val
       AND lookup.dat <> 'All'
  )
  AND dat = 'All'
```